# How to shuffle an array once in functional react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a memory game, i have a shuffle function that shuffles an array of numbers, these numbers are rendered as cards, the problem is that the cards are shuffled every time state changed, i need to only initialize my component with a shuffled array that persists even state is changed!

i tried `useEffect`, but it doesn't work, or i couldn't implement it correctly

code:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];

const shuffle = (arr) => {
//shuffle logic here
}

let shuffledCards;
useEffect(() => {
   shuffledCards = shuffle(numbers) // it doesn't help
}, [])

return(
  <cards shuffledCards={shuffledCards} />
)
```

how can i shuffle my array once instead of every time state is changed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` hook.

```
const shuffle = (arr) => {
  //shuffle logic here
}

const shuffledCards = React.useMemo(() => {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];  
  return shuffle(numbers);
}, [])

return (
  <cards shuffledCards={shuffledCards} />
)
```

Comment: at first glance i thought ```useMemo``` is a helper from another API, but then realized that it is part of react, thank you

Comment: I saw the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), and it says, "You may rely on `useMemo` as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee." So, maybe we shouldn't use it? Is it safe?

Comment: @Faris hmm guess it’s not safe anymore, especially for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is redefining your array `shuffleCards` each render. If you place the array into state it will be stable.

Define `numbers` and `shuffle` outside component as initial state and utility function

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];

const shuffle = array => {
  // shuffle logic
};
```

Component logic: Initialize state and use the effect to shuffle the array on component mount

```
const CardShuffler = () => {
  const [shuffledCards] = useState(shuffle(numbers)); // initialize state

  return <Cards shuffledCards={shuffledCards} />;
};
```

[image: Edit shuffle-cards]

Comment: thank you, but, i implemented the solution, cards start every time with same numbers, i need when to refresh the page starts with cards with shuffled numbers every time, but not with state change, you can imagine i am creating a memory game!

Comment: it worked after i stored that part ```shuffle(numbers)``` in a variable and then use it as an argument for ```setShuffledCards```

Comment: If you handle the case when `shuffledCards = null` in <Card /> then this solution also solve your problem.

Comment: @CodeEagle It took me a moment to understand what you meant, here's a [version](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-morse-4gqjp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) that also factors out the `shuffle` function to be called as an initialization function for `useState`. At this point though it's nearly pointless to store it in state only to be passed on to `Cards`, but perhaps you have more logic going on and what you shared here is just a minimal snippet.